# Where can I find the list of interfaces supported by the WPF WebBrowser.Document from C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, com, webbrowser-control, mshtml

Where can I find the list of interfaces supported by the WPF WebBrowser.Document (namespace system.windows.controls) from C#?

Moreover, where can I find the official documentation from Microsoft web site? The document from MS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.document%28v=vs.110%29.aspx only state this:

*Remarks*

*The Document object needs to be cast to the COM interface you are expecting.*

But I cannot find the list of interfaces that I can expect from this object.

Comment: http://bit.ly/1wuGFET

Comment: @webber2k6 maybe I am not clear. I am not asking the WebBrowser of system.windows.forms, which you are right the document has the interface type. I am asking the WebBrowser of System.Windows.Controls. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can include an reference to `Microsoft.mshtml` to your project.

Then you can use the `mshtml` namespace with the interfaces `IHTMLDocument`, `IHTMLDocument` or `IHTMLDocument[2...5]`. Dont know why there are so many.

They all are implemented by the HTMLDocumentClass. You can get additional info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741317.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can try invoking `wb.Document.GetType().GUID` on the .NET RCW object and see if it's of an expected COM coclass.  You can also try `wb.Document.GetType().GetInterfaces()`.

This might work for HTML, Office and any other component with a type library, but it might not work for objects that don't provide type information, such as C++ components that are **not** implemented on top of a type library, i.e. they use pre-compiled standard marshaling instead.