# WebBrowser encoding UTF-8

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WebBrowser control where I'm showing a local file (htm), this works fine. I also want to set the Encoding to UTF-8. How can I do that?

I tried this solution: [webbrowser encoding problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281137/webbrowser-encoding-problem)

But the webBrowser.Document is an object which doesn't have Encoding property.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Comment: @john I know I can read from html file the Encoding, but my webBrowser dont know that.

Comment: *But the webBrowser.Document is an object which doesn't have Encoding property* .That is strange because according to [the documentation it does have  that property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @rene 
I'm little bit new in this topic.
In my MainWindow.xaml file I have
 <WebBrowser  x:Name="webBrowser" ></WebBrowser>
In my Code behind: webBrowser.Document is an object.

Comment: @rene And your link to Windows Forms, my Application is WPF app.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @rene I have to add reference Windows.Forms and I have to cast this object to HtmlDocument and set the Encoding Property?

Comment: It looks like you need to cast the `Document` to the right interface: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27833944/where-can-i-find-the-list-of-interfaces-supported-by-the-wpf-webbrowser-document

Comment: @rene Yea thanks, I found the solution here in Stackoverflow, but thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: [WPF WebBrowser and special characters like german "umlaute"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902871/wpf-webbrowser-and-special-characters-like-german-umlaute)

Thanks for @BennoDual

```
static void webBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = sender as WebBrowser;
    if(webBrowser == null) {
        return;
    }
    var doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser.Document;           

    doc.charset = "utf-8";
    webBrowser.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: In case you have not reference IHTMLDocument2, you can grab hold of the Document property via using dynamic:
dynamic doc = webBrowser.Document;